# Grails Rest API with OAuth for Mobile App

Tags: api, rest, grails, mobile, oauth

**TL;DR : Read from EDIT 1**.

I'm trying to find a solution to how to implement authentication, especially OAuth for my rest api that will be used by a mobile app.

I have found this popular **plugin** (**Spring Security Rest**):

http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/docs/guide/single.html#oauth[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe02y.jpg)

But the problem is that it's designed for javascript frontend app, so it needs a **callback url** to my frontend to pass the generated token (as you can see in the diagram).

In the case of a mobile application, how can I do that ? Is there another plugin or design that I can implement for this ?
I find it weird that there's really not a lot of plugins or tutorials about stateless OAuth in Grails or Spring but there's ton of mobile apps that use that.

Here's an example of use case :

- User opens mobile app.
- User logs in with facebook on the mobile app.
- User does a request to api/orders which will return him only his orders.

Who should handle the OAuth part in this ? The flow in the diagram presented on the plugin can't work with a mobile app, so should the mobile app auth to facebook, gets the token stores it then passes it to the web app ?

I would like to understand what is the correct design/flow in this case, and if there`s a plugin or a way to implement it using grails.

**EDIT : Is this a correct flow ?**

[image: Mobile App OAuth + Auth to backend with external provider UML Sequence Diagram]

If yes, is there a standard way to implement this with Grails ?

**EDIT 2 :** Now that I understand the flow, I need to integrate the login part with Spring security rest plugin (that already handles everything else).
Here's the code that I want to integrate with the plugin but I don't know where or what to modify in the plugin :

```
    // api/auth/fb
def auth(){

    //Extract fb_access_token
    String fbAccessToken = request.JSON.?fb_access_token

    //Call https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=fbAccessToken
    def userInfo = facebookService. ... (fbAcessToken) //Method to use in the plugin

    //Verify if the userInfo contains an error/doesn't contain a fbId
    if(userInfo.getFbId() == null ){
        respond unauthorized() // 401, Invalid access token
    }
    //Verify if this token is for our app
    else if(userInfo.getAppSecret() != System.env.getParameter("appSecret")){
        respond unauthorized() //401, token not for this app
    }
    //Register or login
    else{
        User user = User.findByFbId(userInfo.getFbId())
        if(user == null){
            facebookService.registerUser(userInfo) //Custom method implemented in the service
        }
        else{
            FbToken fbToken = new FbToken(userInfo.getToken(), userInfo.getExpiration())
            user.setFbAccessToken(fbToken)
        }

        //Login the user with spring security and let it handle the rest (token creation => storage => http answer)

    }

}
```

Comment: did you end up having any luck getting this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Following is what how we tackle facebook connect with grails rest plugin.

1. Client make request to facebook and get fb uid.
2. Client send fb uid to server along with other details such as email, etc etc (whatever fetched from facebook after authentication)

   - Server receive fb uid and **re-authenticate fbuid with facebook** then try to find user with this fbuid in database.
   - If user found login the user with email and return back token.
   - if user not found register and login the user and send back token in response.
3. Client make any subsequent call with token returned from 2nd step.

Comment: How do you make sure that the FB UID is correct ? Do you check it by calling the facebook api before registering or logging in the user ?

Comment: We call the facebook API on client upon success FB should return the uid.

Comment: Thanks. Can you quickly tell me how did you modify the spring security rest plugin to work with this flow ? (especially the login part). And do you have a plugin to recommend to communicate with fb ?
This is the first time I build a web app with auth (or even a web app...)